# apex debug log output does not show up on Eclipse

Tags: plugins, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I installed visualforce plugin to Eclipse 3.6 and is working fine except that
system.debug does not output anything.

**code**

```
static testMethod void testMonth() {
        Month m = new Month(system.today());
        system.debug('foobar');
        system.debug(m.firstDate);
}
```

**step**

In eclipse, right click and select `Force.com`

window popup, select `run test`

Test passes but I'm expecting debug output to show up. (i.e. foobar and date string) but nothing shows up.

Is there anything I might have to turn on or missing?

My Eclipse is Java edition.
I've tried PHP dev edition too with visualforce IDE version 20 but no luck.

Also tried visual force IDE standalone version and this also didn't show the log.

Comment: I don't have Eclipse with Force.com available at the moment but try to play with the sliders that determine how verbose the output is... There should be 2 sliders (or were they dropdowns?) in the Debug window or project settings...

Comment: I've look through Eclipse properties/options where Force.com shows up but none indicates to display debug output. I've seen someone saying to set debug output isActive flag to true but not sure if this is for Eclipse or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a screenshot from my Eclipse: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/709568/stackoverflow/Masato.png

Works like a charm, maybe you closed this "Apex Test Runner" window? Maybe you aren't in the "Force.com" perspective?

Software versions (I don't think it's an Eclipse or plugin problem but you never know)...

```
Eclipse for PHP Developers
Build id: 20100218-1602

Force.com IDE
Version: Summer '10 (19.0.0)
```

Try locating these "Apex Test Runner" and/or "Execute anonymous" windows and playing with dropdown (which says what piece of debug info you want to see) and scrollbar (which says for "this" piece of info how detailed it should be).

Comment: My plugin version is Version: Winter '11 (20.0.0) so it's not outdated or anything...

Comment: http://forums.sforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Apex-Test-Runner-with-Eclipse-IDE-20-0/m-p/210254

Comment: Appeared to be issue only on version 20 :(

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer :) I did not nail the problem but in the end it was helpful, so I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an bug with Force.com IDE Winter'20.0. The fix is making its way through so expect a gud news soon.

Answer (score 1):

Force.com IDE 20.0.1 has been released, which fixes this bug. See http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Force.com_IDE for details.